# Handling some keys while textbox is focused

Tags: c#, winforms

So, apparently I had some problem when handling keys such as `F10` or `F11`.

I want to move the focus from current textbox into another textbox, but not in one particular textbox. So, I wrote some code to handle key:

```
private void checkKeys(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
            {
                buyerName.Focus();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F11)
            {
                discount.Focus();
            }
        }
```

But, if I put this into individual textbox, which kinda hassle to me. Is there any method to listen key whether in global `userControl` or `textbox`?

<s>**Edit :**  here's my structure that I want to ask :</s>

```
Form-
    |-User Control
     |-TextBox
```

**Edit 2 :**  here's some image might help [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmh6B.png)

Comment: The correct way of handling shortcut keys is to override `ProcessCmdKey` method of the `Form`.

Comment: I agree that this would accomplish the same result, and I have updated my answer. But I do not agree that this is the "Correct Way" it is more 'Another Way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a global keyboard listener in Winforms, you just need to add a handler to KeyUp action for the main form itself:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
            e.Handled = true; //To use F10, you need to set the handled state to true
        } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F11)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Then make sure that the KeyPreview property on the main form is set to True.
[image]

The issue with the application freezing when pressing F10 is because it is waiting for another consecutive action. To bypass this simply set the Handled property on the keyevent to TRUE. This releases the unresolved event.

This is my entire form class, refactored to use a helper method as you are refering to. This works fine. But you have to make sure that the KeyPreview property on your form is True, unless your keypresses will not be matched to your event handlers.

```
namespace KeyTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckKeys(e);
        }

        private void CheckKeys(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
            {
                textBox1.Focus();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F11)
            {
                textBox2.Focus();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your comment you are mentioning a UserControl, if you want that, then you need to create an instance method on your UserControl class, and pass the event to that from your global keyboard event handler on your main form.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void HandleKeys(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F11)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then on your main form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckKeys(e);
        }

        private void CheckKeys(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            uc1.HandleKeys(e); //Instance method on your user control.
        }
    }
```

This then works as intended.

As pointed out in one of the comments, a better way would be to override the ProcessCmdKey method on the Form base class. This would be done like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        userControl11.HandleKeys(keyData); // method on the userControl to handle the key code.
        base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The handler on the UserControl stays more or less the same:

```
public void HandleKeys(Keys keys)
    {
        if (keys == Keys.F10)
        {
            nameTB.Focus();
        } else if (keys == Keys.F11)
        {
            emailTB.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Whether this is a more correct way of doing it, I am unsure of. They certainly both accomplish the same result. The documentation shows the first method in for handling keyboard events at the form level here:
[How to handle keyboard input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-at-the-form-level)

But states here that the ProcessCmdKey method is to provide additional handling of shortcuts and MDI accellerators.
[ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey?view=netframework-4.8)

I will leave that up to you to decide what is the best for your scenario. But keep it in to show how you would use it should you choose to.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that :)

Comment: well, somehow i pressed f10 after tried your code inside textbox. it's kinda freeze for a while, and didn't move it's focus

Comment: That sound strange, do you have multiple KeyUp handlers going on at once perhaps?

Comment: nope, just couple keypressEvent inside textbox to detect ```Enter``` key to move it focus.

Comment: Just checked that out, when you use F10 it freezes until one additional input. I believe that is because F10 is used as a System Call short cut. I was able to reproduce this, but changing the listener to use F9 instead of F10 fixed the issue.

Comment: It just work as well. But, the focus won't move. I make a method inside the ```userControl``` to handle focus via ```MainForm``` class. But still, there's no luck :( . You might see the picture I added in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up to the [KeyUp event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keyup?view=netframework-4.8) of your form.

That way, any key pressed while your form is focused will be send to you (if the control didn't handle the key).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Espen and @reza-aghaei for handling keys into main form. Unfortunately, I still didn't managed find a way to focus to designated textbox inside a UserControl. However, I make some dirty method which kinda crappy and un-efficient by searching child control from it's parent

```
//MainForm.cs
if(yourUserControl.Name)//Do some check for targeted userControl, if null can cause NullReferenceException
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
   {
     this.Controls.Find("textboxName", true).First().Focus();
     e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```